# Cannot recognise $startTime as a system.datetime due to a format error

Tags: datetime, powershell

Hi I get this format error when I try and specify the value for a DateTime parameter. Here is my script **which I am running by pressing F5 in Powershell ISE**:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [datetime]$startTime 
)

write-output $startTime
```

When I run it, it says this `Supply values for the following parameters:`. I have tried specifying the following:

```
startTime: get-date
startTime: (get-date)
startTime: new-object DateTime(2015,03,31)
startTime: (new-object DateTime(2015,03,31))
startTime: $(get-date)
startTime: $((get-date))
startTime: $(new-object DateTime(2015,03,31))
startTime: $((new-object DateTime(2015,03,31)))
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot recognise $startTime as a system.datetime due to a format error
```

**UPDATE:**
Turns out you need to specify something like `3/31/2015`.
Why is this? What is wrong with the format for the above `DateTime` objects I used?

Comment: have you tried something simple like `3/31/2015` as the parameter input?

Comment: That works! 
But why? How are the arguments I provided in the wrong format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't exactly duplicate what you are seeing.  Here is my script:

```
7> Get-Content .\startTime.ps1
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [datetime]$startTime
)

write-output $startTime
```

Invoked like so works:

```
8> .\startTime.ps1 (Get-Date)

Monday, March 30, 2015 9:48:01 PM
```

BTW `.\startTime.ps1 get-date` doesn't work because the parameter value is literally the string `get-date` which can't be coerced to a DateTime object. Ditto for `.\startTime.ps1 new-object DateTime(2015,03,31)` because the startTime gets the literal string `new-object` but this does work:

```
10> .\startTime.ps1 (new-object DateTime 2015,03,31)

Tuesday, March 31, 2015 12:00:00 AM
```

The subexpression versions should work as well:

```
11> .\startTime.ps1 $(new-object DateTime 2015,03,31)

Tuesday, March 31, 2015 12:00:00 AM
```

BTW `.\startTime.ps1 3/31/2015` works because the literal string `3/31/2015` can be coerced to a DateTime object.

**UPDATE:** Ah, you are using ISE's mandatory parameter prompting feature. I've run into this issue before. The value supplied here IIRC only gets applied as a string literal i.e. it never evaluates expressions or sub-expressions.

Comment: Instead of calling the script, just have the script open in Powershell ISE and click the play button.

Comment: Ah, you are using ISE's mandatory parameter prompting feature.  I've run into this issue before.  The value supplied here IIRC only gets applied as a string literal i.e. it never evaluates expressions or sub-expressions.

Comment: I guess that's the answer, but I can't mark it as the answer because you wrote it as a comment.